# Implementing a Base64 type in Flow

Tags: ecmascript-6, flowtype

I have a function that returns a base64 encoded value similar to:

```
token = (unencoded:string):string => {
  return Buffer.from(unencoded).toString('base64')
}
```

I'd like to return a type indicating that the contents are base64 encoded.  I could fake this by assigning string to a new type:

```
type Base64 = string
token = (unencoded:string):Base64 => {
  return Buffer.from(unencoded).toString('base64')
}
```

The downside of this is Base64 equals string in typing comparisons, so it's only good as sugar. I'm wondering if there's a way to go deeper and assert things about the string itself?

Comment: I bet not possible in any *static* analysis tool.

Comment: You could make a wrapper of some kind, like wrapping it in a class with `valueOf` and `toString` set up to return the value, but I don't know that there's an easy way otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can kinda fake it:

```
type Encoding<A> = A;
type Base64 = string & Encoding<'base64'>;
const toBase64 = (v: string): Base64 => 
  ((Buffer.from(v).toString('base64'): any): Base64);

function test(aB64String: Base64): void {
  console.log(aB64String);
}

let v = 'blah';

test(v);           
// ^ Cannot call `test` with `v` bound to `aB64String` because string [1] is incompatible with string literal `base64` [2]

test(toBase64(v));
// ^ OK √
```

This way every time you use `Base64` type, you need to pass your string value through the `toBase64` function to get the actual `Base64` typed value.